# graphicsmagick how to remove transparent area and shrink the canvas size of a 32-bit image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick

[image]

Does gm have a command to find out the raster images boundary, and remove transparent area outside this boundary?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
gm convert input.png -trim +repage output.png
```

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

Comment: Does this also work for multiple images in the image?